# Concentration of the empirical moments

Tags: probability, statistics, concentration-of-measure

I do not know of any results on the concentration of empirical moments. More specifically, my problem is :

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ iid sampled by a law $\mathbf{P}$ with moments $\mu_i=\mathbf{E}_{\mathbf{P}}(X^i)$

Let $\overline{X}^{(i)}= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n X_j^i$ for $i\in [m]$ $(m\ge1)$

Let $(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_m) \in \mathbf{R}_+^m$

Can i bound this :

$$ \mathbf{P}(\forall i \in [m], \quad |\overline{X}^{(i)}-\mu_i| \le \epsilon_i )$$.

My first idea was : use classic concentration bound, but it's not natural at all to make assumption like sub-gaussian on the all moments, because if $X$ is subgaussian, then $X^2$ is sub-exponential and we "lose" concentration when powers iterate.

My second idea was to use Central Limit approximation, with non-asymptotic bounds such as Edgeworth Series but we'll have to deal with a very strange co-variance of the moments matrix $\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_{i,j}= \mu_{i+j} - \mu_{i}\mu_{j}$

Any insights on this ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Are the $X_i$ bounded ?

Comment: if you want, any set of assumptions that leads to an interesting solution interests me... At least, we must suppose that the $m$th moment exists, but if you want the $X$ to be bounded, why not... in this hypothesis i guess we can use Hoeffding actually

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of applying Hoeffding if they are bounded (it might be suboptimal though). If they are not... I'll try to think about it.